# Python: MultiValueDictKeyError when running trivial function on uploaded .txt file in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dictionary, keyerror

I'm sorry to ask a simple question that has been asked and answered on this site before, but I am starting to learn Django and I haven't been able to resolve my problem by referring to those [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895588/django-multivaluedictkeyerror-error-how-do-i-deal-with-it) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736141/multivaluedictkeyerror-generated-in-django-after-post-request-on-login-page) or the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects). I have a simple app that lets users upload .txt files, and that works. I now want to add to the app so as to perform a trivial function on the uploaded text files, but I keep getting MultiValueDictKeyError on the line that tries to implement the function. Here is the function I am trying to implement (this is sample_functions.py):

```
def print_file_contents(file_object):
    with open(file_object) as f:
        f = f.decode("utf-8")
        f = f.read()

        print f
```

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Upload(models.Model):
    pic = models.FileField("Choose a text file to upload", upload_to="text/")    
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)

# FileUpload form class.
class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from uploader.models import UploadForm,Upload
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from uploader.resources.sample_functions import print_file_contents

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)       
        if img.is_valid():

            print_file_contents(request.FILES[img])

            img.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fileupload'))
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

Here is my home.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'uploader/style.css' %}" />
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">

    <body>
    <center><h2>Here Be Dragons</h2></center>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p></p>
    </body>


    <center><form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}} 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form></center><p></p><p>Uploaded files:</p>
    {% for img in images %}
        {{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ img.pic.url }}">{{ img.pic.name }}</a>
        ({{img.upload_date}})<hr />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And here is the Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'uploader')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Douglas\Desktop\sample\uploader\views.py" in home
  14.             print_file_contents(request.FILES[img])
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  301.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /upload/
Exception Value: '<uploader.models.UploadForm object at 0x000000000340AEF0>'
```

Does anyone know how I can modify the line `print_file_contents(request.FILES[img])` in views.py or any other part of the workflow so as to be able to print the contents of the uploaded file? I would be very grateful for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. `img` represents the entire form itself, not the image field. The image field is called "pic", so `request.FILES['pic']` would work.

You could have discovered this yourself by printing or logging `request.FILES.keys()` in your view.

Comment: `request.FILES.keys()` was perfect--thank you! I know this is a rather confused jumble; I was trying to find a way to hook into the input file because I want to use that file to query a Whoosh index, but I couldn't read the file because my syntax was off. I can now read the input and throw it to my real function. Thanks again!