# Runtime error while using post methord in forms submision

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Title: Getting Runtime Error (Append Slash) on Submit Button Click

Description:
I'm encountering a runtime error when I click the submit button on my form. The error mentions something about appending a slash. I've tried to understand it, but I'm stuck. Can someone please help me figure out what's causing this error and how to resolve it? I'm using  python with django for my project.

Additional Information:

- [Provide relevant code snippets if possible]
- [Any error messages received]

[image]

```html
  <form  action="register" method="POST" onsubmit="register">
               {% csrf_token %}
               <h3>my information</h3>
               <h4>Contact us today, and get reply with in 24 hours!</h4>
               <style>
                 fieldset {
                   border: medium none !important;
                   text-emphasis-color:black;
                   margin: 0 0 10px;
                   min-width: 100%;
                   padding: 0;
                   width: 100%;
                   }
               </style>
               <fieldset>
                 <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" style="background-color:black;"  required autofocus>
               </fieldset><br>
               <fieldset>
                 <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" style="background-color:black;" required>
               </fieldset><br>
               <fieldset>
                 <input placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="tel" tabindex="3" style="background-color:black;" required>
               </fieldset><br>
               <fieldset>
                 <label for="account">Choose a account:</label>
                   <select name="account" id="name">
                   <option value="netflix">netflix</option>
                   <option value="amazone prime">amazone</option>
                   <option value="disney plus hotstar">hotstar</option>
                   </select>
                   <style>
                   #nname {
                     padding: 5px;
                     color: #f7f7f8;
                     font-size: 12px;
                     background: black;
                     appearance: none;
                 
                 }
               </style>
               </fieldset><br>
               <fieldset>
                 <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." tabindex="5" style="background-color:black;" required></textarea>
               </fieldset><br>
               <fieldset>
                 <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" style="background-color:rgb(23, 12, 12);" data-submit="...Sending" value="submit">Submit</button>
               </fieldset><br>
             </form>
```

view.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def register(request):
    name=request.POST['name']
    email=request.POST['email']
    phone_number=request.POST['phone_number']
    account=request.POST['account']
    message=request.POST['message']


    user=User.objects.create_user(name=name)
    print("we wil call back you")
    return redirect('/')
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.views import View

from .import views


urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.index,name='index'),
        path('contact/', views.contact,name='contact'),
        path('ideagained/',views.ideagained,name='ideagained'),
        path('idea/',views.idea,name='idea'),
        path('ouridea/',views.ouridea,name='ouridea'),
        path('aboutpage/',views.aboutpage,name='aboutpage'),
        path('register/',views.register,name='register')
        
]
```

Comment: None of your `input`s have `name`s. Where do you think, say, `phone_number` will come from?

Answer (score 0):

change

```html
  <form action="register" method="POST" onsubmit="register">
```

to

```html
  <form action="register/" method="POST" onsubmit="register">
```

That should do the trick iirc

Otherwise follow the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) about how to disable append slash

Comment: after do that, I got "MultiValueDictKeyError at /register/" error.

Comment: Might be worth looking on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652978/6110086

Comment: still i got error like "TypeError at /register/

UserManager.create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username' "

Comment: Hello @jeeva . Lala Sabathil's answer is right.  "MultiValueDictKeyError at /register/" error is another error not related to this question. Post a new question or look in stack search for that error.